# Does Coda 2 support Markdown?

Tags: plugins, coda, markdown

Is there a plugin for **Coda 2** that interprets the `Markdown` langage please ?

Comment: It's probably worth checking the website for the software (http://panic.com/coda/plugins.php) before posting a question here.

Comment: true :) I've missed it it was in front of me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Coda plugins page](http://panic.com/coda/plugins.php):

> ### [Markdown.codaplugin](https://github.com/Ibmurai/Markdown.codaplugin) - A Markdown plugin for Coda
>
> #### Usage
>
> - Use CTRL+ALT+CMD+C to convert to HTML
> - Use CTRL+ALT+CMD+P to preview